# CDynLinkLibrary market memory leak

Tags: c++, checkmarx

I am currently reviewing a legacy code where the CDynLinkLibrary is used and I am analyzing the code in an analysis tool (checkmarx) that reports vulnerabilities in it. The code is implemented as shown on your [page](https://help.perforce.com/stingray/2020.1/Stingray_Studio_HTML_User_Guide/index.html#page/Stingray%20Studio/ogug-advconcepts.045.1.html#), except that when creating the object of type CDynLinkLibrary, a pointer to this object is stored in the lib variable and it is at this point that I get memory leak. Is it normal for this to happen?

```
static AFX_EXTENSION_MODULE TestDll1DLL = { NULL, NULL };
extern "C" int APIENTRY
DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    // Remove this if you use lpReserved
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpReserved);
 
    if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
      TRACE0("TESTDLL1.DLL Initializing!\n");
      
      // Extension DLL one-time initialization
      if (!AfxInitExtensionModule(TestDll1DLL, hInstance))
        return 0;
      // comments deleted
 
      CDynLinkLibrary *lib = new CDynLinkLibrary(TestDll1DLL);
    }
    else if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)
    {
      TRACE0("TESTDLL1.DLL Terminating!\n");
      // Terminate the library before destructors are called
      AfxTermExtensionModule(TestDll1DLL);
    }
    return 1;   // ok
}
```

I have tried to free the memory using delete lib, however using this option the program stops working. I have also found a tip that many leak detection techniques will try too soon before these objects can be released.